# Get unix timestamp Azure App Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

How would I `project` the unix timestamp for when my data was logged in Azure through Azure App Insights? I know I can use `now()` to get the current timestamp, but what about the timestamp of a row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every table in AppInsights has a "timestamp" column, which marks when the event occurred.

In order to convert to Unix timestamp, try this:

```
requests
| take 1
| project unixtime = tolong(timestamp - datetime(1970-01-01)) / 10000000
```